# What do I do after retopologing?

Tags: topology

I made my Low-poly model since the High-poly mesh was too messy and laggy but then I realized that the Low-poly mesh looks too jagged. I want it to resemble the High-poly mesh but don't know what to do. What do I do??

Btw I'm new to retopology and might have made the squares quite un-uniform. There are no triangles but the sizes differ a bit. I heard that it needs to be uniformly tiled but I think it's quite impossible. Is it OK? Here's a photo.[image]

Comment: Do a search for images that show hand topology. If you intend to rig and animate you have to control the **edge flow**. Avoid ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices) those will only give you problems.

Comment: @cegaton Then which is better? A triangle or a pentagon? And what about the size and shape of the quadrangles?

Comment: https://topologyguides.com/